# Subwindow stuck inside its titlebar

Tags: windows, windows-11, window

### Problem Context

I've been using Logic Friday *(version 1.1.4, can't find the official website anywhere but a simple search should do the trick)* to work out all the complex logic gates for something I've been wanting to do in [Digital Logic Sim](https://sebastian.itch.io/digital-logic-sim). So far, it has been working well, but unfortunately, I made the mistake of minimizing the window while I was using its 'Trace Gate Logic' tool, and this brings us to...

### The Problem

[image: Titlebar against a green background, no other window is present, and the maximize button is greyed out. (Image Link, don't have enough reputation for a proper inline)]

The tiny little title-bar you see above has been causing me a **lot** of trouble. *(Context: The window is supposed to be a "Trace Logic" window, made to simulate what happens when inputs are toggled in a generated diagram)* Nothing I've done so far has been able to restore it back to normal. Minimizing the window lead me to the problem, and closing the window doesn't restore it, so the two buttons are out. The edges of the screen(s), and various shortcuts that move the windows around do nothing to restore it, and not even restarting or reinstalling the program was able to get the window back to normal.

Is there a way that I can restore the window back so that I can continue to use it, and if possible, what can I do to ensure I'll never have to deal with the problem again?

Comment: I assume restarting the client isn’t an option?

Comment: Unfortunately so, if restarting was able to fix the issue, I wouldn't be opening this issue.

Comment: Your not opening an issue, we can’t fix a defect in the application, your asking other people who might have an idea how to reset the behavior of the application. Why did you remove your image? How can we help without your screenshot?

Comment: I think superuser might've eaten my edit, should be there now.
(Update: Thanks for the help, by the way!)

Comment: select the "window" (aka titlebar).  Press [Alt]+[Space].  Don't touch your mouse and downarrow to `size` and hit [Enter].  Use the arrow keys to try to stretch out the window this way.

Comment: Tried that; Size is unfortunately greyed out too.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of a window are stored *somewhere* on your PC. The simplest solution is to delete the current setting, and the next time that application closes, it will store the current size. However, *finding* that location may take a bit of work.

- Some installed applications store layout in the Windows Registry. For example, MS Notepad uses `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad\iWindowPosDX` for width. It is safe to delete those layout values.
- Some applications, particularly portable ones, store layout in the same folder as the applications itself. Notepad++ uses `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\config.xml` to retain layou in `<GUIConfig name="AppPosition" x="0" y="0" width="1100" height="700" isMaximized="no" />`. Delete (or alter) just those values to restore the window to default size.
- Some applications use the AppData folder. E.G., Restore Point Creator uses `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Restore_Point_Creator\<key>\1.0.0.0\user.config` for layout in `<setting name="windowSize" serializeAs="String"> <value>536, 603</value>`. Alter that value to restore the window's size.

There might be other places, but those are where to start the search *for Logic Friday* to restore the window layout.

A less elegant method would be to uninstall the application, and the remove all mention of it from AppData, from the Registry, and from the folder in which it had been installed, and reinstall, but it's a remedy of last resort.

Comment: Also, process monitor would show OP where the settings are coming from but there is a learning curve with procmon and filters.